# when using [(ngModel)] directive, what is the event expression called to detect change?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Using [(ngModel)]="value" directive inside an Input control which is rendered as a range slider. The two-way binding side of this works nicely,  but I would like to be able to fire off some code when the value changes.

What expression/function name should I use with this form of ngModel binding? Documentation doesn't seem to indicate this unless I'm missing something.

Comment: `(ngModelChange)="valueHasChanged()"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two separate binders

```
[ngModel]="value"
```

and

```
(ngModelChange)="someFunction"
```

You can manually listen to the model change using `ngModelChange` `@Output`.

Comment: So basically I have to revert to 2 x 1-Way bindings to be able to view the events?

Comment: @Mark no. You can use [(ngModel)] and (ngModelChange)

Comment: You can combine them both. If you only want to do another job with assigning the value, you can still use as @JBNizet commented above

Answer (score 4):

You may listen to `(ngModelChange)` event invoked upon `ngModel` value change.

```
(ngModelChange)="takeAction()"
```

-

```
takeAction() {
   // called invoke when value of `ngModel` Changes
}
```